# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error in unix shell script. Help finding bug?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, review

Now, I already know that this means that there is a bug, But I cant find it. Could you help review my code and try to spot what is wrong?
The error message revolves around the date function I created. All the other functions work fine in this code.

Error:

```
sguthrie1@cs:~$ ./finalproject.sh -d 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Code:

```
function check
{
        echo "usage: hw14.sh option argument
Please enter one or more options or arguments."
        exit
}
function date
{
        if [[ $myvar == "-d" ]]
        then date "+%d %B,%Y"
        fi
}
function host
{
        if [[ $myvar == "-h" ]]
        then hostname
        fi
}
function who
{
        if [[ $myvar == "-w" ]]
        then whoami
        fi
}
function help
{
        if [[ $myvar == "-help" ]]
        then echo "
valid options:
-d = display today's date in day-month-year format
-h = display name of computer you are currently working on
-w = display who you are logged in as
arguments:
Any argument entered is checked to see if it is a file name
"
        fi
}
if [ $# -le 0 ]
then check
fi
for myvar
do
        if [[ $myvar == "-"* ]]
        then date; host; who; help
        fi
done
```

Comment: After looking at what you guys said, I just changed the name of my function. Tanks for the help.

Comment: You can always run gdb on the core dump to find out exactly where the program is crashing...in this case, happily, gdb is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

The `date` function is calling itself recursively with no termination condition. This will [probably always segfault](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2012-07/msg00004.html) in Bash. Use `command date` to call the date command instead of the function. In bash 4.2 you can also set a recursion depth limit by setting the `FUNCNEST` variable to help detect such errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your `date` function is inadvertently calling itself. You can either rename your function to avoid the conflict, or refer to the system command more specifically as `/bin/date`.

Comment: Or call `command date` instead of `date` to make the shell use the command found in `PATH`.